# Acumatica AR303000 "First Due Date" DateTime Format

Tags: sql-server, datetime, format, acumatica

I'm getting Info data from Screens via Web Api in Acumativa v6.

General Configuration, Locales and User profile locales formats, are both in en-Us: Short date "YYYY-MM-DD" LongTime "HH:MM:SS".

The Screens and GI work just fine and I get dates with the locales formats.

But, in this particular Screen AR303000,  when I read the "First Due Date" data field, the format returned is "MM/DD/YYY h:m:ss AM"; I'm sure this come that way from MSSQL bypassed by Acumatica

Q: How can I change the MSSQL format to "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"?

or can that be done via Acumatica settings or parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using C# I would advise against using the returned string value directly.
Both formats can be converted to a DateTime object with the same code. Once you have converted the text string to a DateTime object, your data has been validated and sanitized so you're free to convert it to whatever format you need.

**This will work, even if the date string received from the API changes format:**

[image]

**Here I inverted the format to show the same method works for most standard format:**

[image]

**By doing this, your code is not dependent on the input string format and your program will be more resistant to configuration changes that could break it.**
                                                   EDIT adding WinDev code
Native:

```
sDate est une chaîne
sDate = DateSys()
Res = ChaîneVersDate(sDate, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")
```

Standard:

```
sDate is string     
sDate = DateSys()
Res = StringToDate(sDate, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")
```

Comment: Using Windev in my side; but I like the aproach you'd used; I will mimic the TryParse method. I also realized that the "First Due Date" is READONLY, so I will blank that field when Insert/Update records. But TryParse will do the duty me. Thank You!

Comment: In Windev WLanguage, the equivalent method is StringToDate or DateVersChaine or 日期转换为字符串. Ref: https://help.windev.com/?3027013

Comment: wrong one: I meant ChaineVersDate not DateVersChaine